# When perform tomography, do I get back to the classical information $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2$ that I embedded in qubit?

Tags: quantum-circuit, state-tomography

Imagine I have a classical data(normalised to fit qubit) in the form of$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2$ I assumed data to be in qubit
$$\left| \psi \right> = (\alpha_1 + i\alpha_2 ) \left|0\right> + (\beta_1 + i\beta_2 )\left|1\right>$$

If I use any quantum circuit I know I will lose some information if I measure it? I was reading about tomography, so if perform tomography, will I get back to the classical information $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2$ that I embedded in qubit?

Comment: tomography works by repeatedly measuring the state (by which I mean, preparing multiple independent copies of the same state and performing a measurement on each one), if that's what you're asking. So "performing tomography before measuring" doesn't make a whole lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer:

If you perform state tomography you will recover *ALL* the
information within the state to within the precision/number of times you
repeated the measurement (except for an overall global phase term). I.e. you will recover all four real numbers
$\alpha_1,$ $\alpha_2,$ $\beta_1,$ and $\beta_2$ to a precision related to the
number and quality of repeated measurements you make (or rather combinations of these four numbers which are ambiguous to within a global phase term as shown below).

## Long answer:

For simplicity I'm going to write the state as
$\left|\psi\right\rangle  = \alpha \left|0\right\rangle  + \beta\left|1\right\rangle,$
where $\alpha = \alpha_1+i\alpha_2$ and $\beta = \beta_1+i\beta_2$ are taken as
complex numbers (which if you know the amplitude and phase you recover both
numbers/all the information).

In general, tomography measures the density operator
$\rho = \left|\psi\right\rangle\!\left\langle\psi\right|,$
not the state $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ (because in general neither states or
measurements are perfect/pure). Written as a matrix, the density operator is
\begin{equation}
    \rho_{mn}= \langle m |\rho|n\rangle
    =\begin{pmatrix}
        |\alpha|^2 & \alpha\beta^*\\
        \alpha^*\beta & |\beta|^2
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $m,n = 0 \text{ or } 1$.

To experimentally measure $\rho$ we make multiple different projection
measurements. If we make a set of projection measurements using a set of
states $|\phi\rangle$, then the measurement
$\hat{\pi}\equiv|\phi\rangle\!\langle\phi|$ will be found with the following
rate/probability
$$P=\text{Tr}\,{(\hat{\pi}\rho)}=\langle\phi|\rho|\phi\rangle.$$
So for instance if you make a measurement in the 0/1 basis, you will either
measure $|0\rangle$ with probability $|\alpha|^2$ or $|1\rangle$ with
probability $|\beta|^2 = 1 - |\alpha|^2$. I.e. you will gain (at most) 1 bit of
precision for the relative amplitude of either state (exactly 1 bit if the
measurement is assumed to be perfect and have no noise).

In order to measure the off diagonal elements (e.g. the phase of $\alpha$ and
$\beta$), you need to measure in a different basis (equivalent to first applying an
appropriate gate to your qubit to rotate into the basis you want). For example
if you measure in the basis
$$|\phi\rangle = |0\rangle\pm |1\rangle$$
(e.g. by first applying a Hadamard gate to your qubit) we will find
probabilites
$$P_\pm=\text{Tr}\,(\hat{\pi}_\pm\rho)=\rho_{00}+\rho_{11}\pm(\rho_{01}+\rho_{10}) = |\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 \pm (\alpha\beta^* + \beta\alpha^*) .$$
Now $\rho_{01}+\rho_{10}=\rho_{01}+\rho_{01}^*=2\Re{(\rho_{01})}$ so we
can get from a differential measurement (to avoid miscalibration errors)
$$\Re{(\rho_{01})} =\Re{(\alpha\beta^*)} =(P_+-P_-)/4.$$

In order to find $\Im{(\rho_{01})}$ we need to measure in a 3rd basis. To get
the imaginary part of
$\rho_{12}$, we can measure $|\phi\rangle=|0\rangle\pm i|1\rangle$ and
follow a similar procedure as before which gives
$$P'_\pm = \text{Tr}\,(\hat{\pi}_\pm\rho)=\rho_{11}+\rho_{22}\pm i(\rho_{12}-\rho_{21}).$$
Taking the difference of these two rates allows one to find the imaginary part
of $\rho_{01}$ which is given by
$$\Im{(\rho_{01})} =\Im{(\alpha\beta^*)} =(P'_+-P'_-)/4.$$

Comment: According to your "short answer", this protocol would allow one to recover coefficients $\alpha_1 = 0, \alpha_2=1, \beta = 0$ for one choice of input state, and then recover the coefficients $\alpha_1 = 1, \alpha_2=0, \beta = 0$ for another choice of input state, right? This implies you could distinguish $i|0\rangle$ from $|0\rangle$, even though $\rho$ is identical in both cases. For this claim to be true you probably need to restrict which choices of coefficients are allowed (e.g., require $\alpha_2 = 0$ or "$|\psi\rangle$ up to global phase")

Comment: @forky40: Yes, global phases are considered unreal. Notice, you always get a real output, i.e. only terms such as $|\alpha|^2$ or $\alpha\beta^*\pm (\alpha\beta^*)^*$, so inverting to get $\alpha$ or $\beta$ will always be ambiguous within a global phase

Comment: Right, so your answer is not quite correct. After performing tomography, you will _not_ recover the four real constants $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2$, unless you impose additional requirements on these constants. Regarding the OP's question, they _cannot_ get back the classical information embedded in $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2$ in general.

Comment: So what was the right way to recover those?

Comment: @forky40 I edited to add a caveat related to the immeasurability of the global phase (at least assuming single qubit state tomography)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to prepare the state $|\psi\rangle$. Then the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule#Details) says that upon measuring you will obtain outcome $|0\rangle$ with probability $\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2$ and outcome $|1\rangle$ with probability $\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2$. So to obtain an estimate of the parameter $\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2$ or $\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2$ you would require multiple preparations and measurements, but either way, you wouldn't be able to recover the individual $\alpha_i$ or $\beta_j$ values.

A more common thing to do is to prepare the state $|\phi\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ with the desired real parameter $\alpha$ (then $\beta=1-\alpha^2$). In this case a party that has access to $|\phi\rangle$ can use [Amplitude Estimation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/finance/tutorials/00_amplitude_estimation.html) to obtain an estimate of $\alpha$ or $\beta$, however in this case, one needs the access to the operation $A$ that prepares $|\phi\rangle$ i.e. $A|0\rangle=|\phi\rangle$.

Comment: So I cannot use complex amplitudes if I want to recover?

Comment: @User1086 precisely.

Comment: This is absolutely false. Tomography gives you the full complex numbers. However, to get the phases out, you need to measure in different bases than just the 0/1 basis (it's called tomography b/c of these different measurements)

Comment: I wasn't describing tomography. Also from my understanding tomography only allows one to learn the values of the density matrix... this is different than the complex amplitudes of a state no?